# What is this SOT23-5 component marked pD?

Tags: identification, sot23

[image]
Spent quite a bit time but could not identify 'U13' SOT23-5 component with the marking 'PD'.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The marking looks to have a lower case 'p' and an upper case 'D', i.e. `pD`.

From [The ultimate SMD marking codes database selecting a marking of PD](https://smd.yooneed.one/code5044.html) the matching device is a `74AUP1GU04GW` in a `SOT-353-1` package from NXP Semiconductors which is a *CMOS logic IC,
Single unbuffered inverter*

The [74AUP1GU04](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AUP1GU04.pdf) NXP datasheet shows `74AUP1GU04GW` has:

- Package `SOT353-1`
- Marking code `pD`
- Pinout:

  [image]

> Spent quite a bit time but could not identify 'U13' **SOT23-5** component with the marking 'PD'.

The question says the package is `SOT23-5`, rather than the `SOT353-1` from the above identified device `74AUP1GU04GW`.

The Wikipedia page [SOT23-5, SOT353, SOT553](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-outline_transistor#SOT23-5,_SOT353,_SOT553) shows there are some dimension differences between `SOT23-5` and `SOT353-1`. Maybe worth trying to precisely measuring the dimensions of `U13` on the PCB to confirm which package it is, since from just looking at it might be difficult to tell a `SOT23-5`.vs. `SOT353-1`.

Comment: Combinations of dashes dots are traceability markings used by NXP/Nexperia so it is a match for me.